# EJOR format in Latex

Tags: elsarticle, journal

Can anyone help me to find a latex manuscript template for European Journal of Operational Research with exactly in this format?
[image: EJORformat]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked into using the [elsarticle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/) document class? Load with either the `3p` or the `5p` class option to get two-column layout.

Comment: I believe the format is proprietary; Elsevier provides the `elsarticle` class for submissions, it's the copy editors' job to apply the changes for a particular journal.

Comment: See [Elsevier LaTeX instructions](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions). There you also find links to download the current version of the style files.